# Who was Eliezer's Father?

Tags: eliezer

Who was Eliezer (i.e. servant of Avraham) father?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Torah just introduces him as a Damascene.

But I believe one medrish identifies him as Nimrod's son.  Eliezer was tired of his father's worldview and sought out Avraham's monotheism.

Comment: IIRC one version has Nimrod giving his son to Avraham as a slave.

Comment: @yitznewton that's certainly possible though I haven't heard it before. Are you sure you're not confusing that with the one about Hagar being Pharaoh's daughter? Nimrod and Avraham weren't exactly best buddies.

Comment: @Shalom: it's in [Pirkei d'R. Eliezer ch. 16](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21858&pgnum=107): after Avraham got out of the furnace of Ur Kasdim safely, all of the VIPs of the kingdom gave him presents, and Nimrod did too. (Actually, though, PdRE has Eliezer as Nimrod's slave. The idea that he was Nimrod's son is from Targum Yonasan to Gen. 14:14, which calls him בר נמרוד.)

Comment: @Alex, huh. That would imply that Nimrod felt impressed, rather than threatened, by Avraham post-furnace. ? Interesting. It's funny how people weave different midrashim together. I was taught in grade school about Lot's daughter who secretly gave a fellow  girl jars of flour, and was killed by bees for it -- when I looked into it, that appears to be a mashup of several different midrashim.

Comment: @Alex yes, now I remember: slave-Og was the gift of Nimrod - I mixed them up indeed.

Comment: Og was the fugitive who informed Avraham about the war of the kings having taken Lot captive. And Nimrod was one of the kings in that war.

Answer (score 13):

According to Targum Yonoson - 14:14 (in Bereishis), Eliezer's father was Nimrod.

Answer (score 13):

Another Midrash (Bereishis Rabbah 60:7) identifies Eliezer with Canaan. According to that, then, his father would have been Ham, Noach's son (Gen. 10:6).

Answer (score 3):

Pirkei d'Rebbi Eliezer has Eliezer as Og King of the Bashan.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, though, does it?

Comment: Huh. That's really head-scratcher.

Comment: @msh210 not per se, just mentioning another position on Eliezer's identity that would trickle up to his father's identity.

Comment: So Pirkei d'Rabi Eliezer would say the "refugee" who informed Avraham of the battle of Sdom was *not* Eliezer, I assume.

Comment: Gee if you mix Midrashim here, this guy has a one-man show. He comes to tell Avraham of the war, then he's Avraham's army that goes and fights!

Comment: According to the Talmud (Niddah 61A) and commentaries, this would make Eliezer's father Schemchazel: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/how-were-achiman-sheshai-and-talmai-sons-of-giants

Comment: @shalom refugee was an angel, Michael IIRC

Comment: These midrashim are fascinating. Another related topic: Terach and his attitude(s) to Avram

Comment: @yitznewton, yes there's another opinion in the medrish that it was an angel, not Og. As Rabbi Sorotzkin (moznayim l'torah) points out, sometimes we can't tell if the person doing a given action is the loftiest angel or the most awful scoundrel!