# Source for God creating the world to test the angels/souls

Tags: sources-mekorot, malach-angel, soul, free-will-bechira, heaven

Is there a jewish source (even remotely) simmilar to the following story:

> The angels/souls* in heaven were praising God, saying how awesome and great
> God is, but God said to them "you only praise Me because you have no
> other choice (since in heaven God's existence and awesomeness is obvious and
> undeniable), I will create the world in which you'll have complete
> free will to serve Me or not, let's see if you will truly serve Me." And He put the angels/souls in the world as human beings, and that's why we are here.

(*I'm hereby conflating angels with souls, i dont know if this is correct as angels are perhaps higher than souls.)

Is there any midrash or kabballah (or any other jewish source) that has a story like this, or did I just totally make this up?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34760/27180

Comment: There is half a legit idea here. Hashem made free will so we could serve Him freely, rather than by the force of seeing His glory, which nullifies everything (see e.g. Tanya Shaar Yichud v'Emuna). But He made humans with souls for this, not angels. Angels are a different being. See first part of Derech Hashem. There IS a midrash that the nefilim mentioned in Bereshit Ch. 4 are angels who complained about humans sinning so Hashem said "if you were a human you would sin worse" and He sent them down. See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/131238/31534

Comment: Chapter 6 sorry

Comment: @RabbiKaii thank you. I think that is were I heard it from. I was wondering if there is a simillar story for humans but maybe not.

Comment: @Jim chassidic commentary on the story of the shunamis woman comes to mind. So does the story of Chava and the tree. I'll think around for more similarities. It's a very central theme