# What happened to Noah's slaves?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, parashat-noach, slave-serve-eved-avadim, mabul

According to such commentators or *midrashim* as say that Noah had slaves that joined him on the ark<sup>[1]</sup>, what happened to them? That is: We hear a lot in the immediately succeeding chapters of Genesis (and of course in the rest of Tanach) about Noah's own descendants; did the slaves have any descendants? Did they remain slaves of Noah's descendants? Were any freed (or did any escape slavery)? Did any became separate peoples? Which?

---

<sup>[1] e.g.,  [*Haamek Davar* to Genesis 7:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haamek_Davar_on_Genesis.7.1.2-3?lang=he)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Og was Noachs slave Pirkei derav Eliezer 23:

> וישאר אך נח ואשר אתו בתבה וחוץ **מעוג מלך הבשן** שישב לו עץ אחד מן הסולמות של התיבה ונשבע לנח ולבניו **שיהיה להם עבד עולם**

The only other other survivors of the flood except Noach and his family were Og and acccoring to tosfos Niddah 61b Sichon also survived as he was Ogs brother and pair mentioned in Gemara Niddah 61b. Alternatively the Rosh says Ogs mother survived and Sichon was born after the flood as every pair was male and female. See [Nephilim after the Flood](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96419/nephilim-after-the-flood/96420#96420).

Og and his Mother/brother were freed after the flood see [Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.16?lang=bi) which paved the way to Og's Kingship of Bashan. So Sichon is decended from Og's Mother, and Devarim 2,33 mentions that Sichon had a son :וַנַּ֥ךְ אֹת֛וֹ וְאֶת־בנו [בָּנָ֖יו] וְאֶת־כָּל־עַמּֽוֹ, and since Both Sichon and Og's people Confronted the Israelites with war and were all killed, there are no living descendants nowadays.

Comment: -1. I see nothing about this on _Nida_ 61 _amud_ 2. (And even if I did, how do you know that those who say that slaves were on the boat agree with that _g'mara_? — especially because you say it's not the _g'mara_ itself but as "explained by the Rishonim".)

Comment: @msh210 if you would have read the Hebrew of Pirkei Derav Eliezer brought in the link you would have seen that Og became Noachs slave and was the only survivor, the gemora NIDA says Hapalit which means the survivor singular which means no one else survived but the rishonim explain that Og did survive with a pair. Though no-one else  survived. read the source carefully but it's very kind to give feedback as too many people downvote anonymously